# How can I get many addresses from many trajectories with bash script without error?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, web

I have many trajectories data. 500k. I try to get adresses of these coordinates. I use bash command in linux.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"

while  read -r line
do
uid=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,)
lat=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,)
long=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d,)
timestamp=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d,)
printf "$uid,$lat,$long,$timestamp|"
wget -O- -q "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false"|\
      grep formatted_address|\
      head -n1|\
      cut -d\> -f2|\
      cut -d\< -f1
done < "$filename"
```

I can only get 2500 addresses. After 2500 coordinates, This command "wget" is not work. When I reset modem, I can get 2500 more addresses. Is there any way to get address from coordinates? Or is it possible to reset IP in bash command after getting 2500 address ? thanks.

My input file include 500k data like this
`11395,39.9050283,32.6977617,2008-11-03T16:58:05Z`
my coordinates `39.9050283,32.6977617`

My output file will be like this `11395,39.9050283,32.6977617,2008-11-03T16:58:05Z|11395,39.9051033,32.6984550,2008-11-03T16:58:06Z|Erler, Eskişehir Yolu No:120, 06790 Etimesgut/Ankara, Turkey`

Comment: Ahmet, When modem is ON according the DSL service provider will assign the public IP. And when you try wget on google.map, google has a restriction by preventing connection after 2500 hits. Please contact your service provider to reset modem from bash command. It will be vary for each modem. What is your modem type?.

Comment: airties rt 211.. Is there another way? For example use dns and change adress of dns ?

Comment: i dont think we can reset from command line for arities tr 211, try split 2500 coordinate from 500k file and open 192.168.0.1 from browser login and toosl -> reset modem, use it.

Comment: https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/  . works offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that Google is throttling your API requests. There's a limit to how much data they let you get through a free service. Apparently, after 2500 requests, they cut you off. When you “reset modem”, you evidently get a different IP address from your ISP, so you can make another 2500 requests before you get blocked there.

You need to rethink your strategy. For 500k requests, you may need to pay for a service, or get the data from different sources such as OpenStreetMap. If you get the data from OpenStreetMap, consider that while it's free, they still won't appreciate you making too many requests in a short time. If you need so much data, maybe you should download some databases and do local queries.